# Number of bits in basic data type

Tags: c, byte, sizeof, bit

Here's a couple of thoughts.I'm learning so there might be mistake(s) and even missing some basics.

1. `sizeof` operator returns number of bytes.
2. `number of bits in byte` is not constant value(correct me but it's number of bits char has).
3. I want to know how many bits variable occupies, and sizeof won't tell me that without making assumptions about number of bits in char.

So I came up with this piece of (probably unnecessary) code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
  double bits;

  bits=sizeof(int)*log10(UCHAR_MAX+1)/log10(2);

  printf("Bits = %lf\n", bits);

  return 0;
}
```

Is there easier (standard) way to check how many `bits` given type occupies?
`CHAR_BIT * sizeof(type)` will do the job, but is there standard `one argument` macro/function that does that for me?
Someone with better mathematical background could check if my code will be always giving correct answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is char guaranteed to be exactly 8-bit long in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881894/is-char-guaranteed-to-be-exactly-8-bit-long-in-c)

Comment: @drahnr it is not, it's completely different question. I know how char/byte can have different size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check for how many bits the machine actually used for a single char use the `CHAR_BIT` macro (note that `sizeof (char)` will always return one by definition though the actual allocation size per char may be still taller (even 32bits) though wasteful)

---

I am not aware of any predefined macro, but

```
#define REAL_BITS(type) (CHAR_BIT*sizeof(type))
```

should suffice

Comment: I missed that one from limits.h. Now that I checked I think that is CHAR_BIT. Is there single argument standard defined macro/fuction that takes data type and returns number of bits?(Put that in an answer with correction and that will be something I can accept).

Answer (score 3):

```
const size_t numberOfBits = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(type);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using CHAR_BIT (defined in limits.h) should do it.

```
CHAR_BIT * sizeof(something)
```

I have checked a number of *nix platforms and they are all 8 bits in a byte, but I guess it may vary on some stranger platforms.

Comment: I don't think that's how standard defines byte.

Comment: You're right, you can use CHAR_BIT (definied in limits.h), but it is 8 bits in all the platforms I have checked.

Comment: And I was looking for answer always true in C, without making assumptions. CHAR_BIT is something I was missing, but can't accept that answer because of 8-bit byte part.

Comment: 8 is minimum by standard. `CHAR_BIT` may be more than that.

Comment: `sizeof` does NOT return size in 8-bit bytes. The definition is that `char`has size 1, and `char` may be more than 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

char data type is a byte. a int is 4bytes (dword). short is 2bytes (word). so, how many bits?
just sizeof(the_char)*8.
when you want to convert bytes to bits just bits_number=bytes_number*8
:)

Comment: I think char will be always 8bit. even you are under 64bit system. What i know is char is a byte data type. 2 "chars" or 2 bytes can be a short integer (2bytes,16bits) etc...

Comment: In assembly when I push a byte (char) into stack it has 8bits. I can debug it and watch the stack.