# How to find Processor word size on 8/16/32 bit machine using c

Tags: c, linux

Is it true that the size of word will depend on the processor?
For 8 bit processor it is 8 bit?
for 16 bit processor it's 16?
For 32 bit processor it will be 32 bit?
Is there any universal rule to define word length on 8/16/32 bit machine?

Comment: The size is what `sizeof` says: `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(size_t)`, `sizeof(void*)` are the most important sizes. Multiply by CHAR_BIT to get the number of bits.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define 'word'. In the popular definition, a word is always 16 bits. But since you are referring to the C programming language, I assume you want to know the width of type `int`. This has been asked many times already, for example here: [Number of bits in a data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090750/number-of-bits-in-a-data-type)

Comment: _[A] word is always 16 bits_ was only a classic definition from Microsoft's MS-DOS / 16-bit MS-Windows / WinAPI and I believe Intel-syntax x86 assembly point-of-view. In general a [word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) is natural unit of data on a particular processor.

Comment: @mctylr I stand corrected. I don't know who started abusing the term, but Intel made an important contribution by breaking with the original definition, and making 'word' synonymous with 16 bits of data in the documentation of an 8-bit processor (the 8080). Not even 32-bit microprocessors could erase that memory. I have edited my post, replacing 'classic' by the more appropriate 'popular'.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it true that the size of word will depends on the processor.

Yes, if by "size of word" you mean the size of general registers of your processor.

> Is there any universal rule to define word length on 8/16/32 bit machine?

No, not in C.

Answer (score 0):

That's broadly true for most processors today, so a simple `sizeof(void*)` will tell you the number of bytes per address.

However, while it's typical for modern machines, as you can see in [this table from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29#Table_of_word_sizes), it hasn't always been a useful rule.